# Modelling an IF-THEN statement with multiple conditions in Mixed Integer Linear Programming (MILP)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, traveling-salesman, mixed-integer-programming, operations-research

I need some help modelling the following logic as a mixed integer linear programming constraints for a vehicle routing problem.

**The  Variables involved are the following:**

1. X<sub>ij</sub>, SDV<sub>lmj</sub>, and MDV<sub>hkbj</sub> are
   binary decision variables.    They equal to 1 when a certain link (ij) or route/path (lmj or
   hkbj) is    passed.
2. SOC<sup>L</sup><sub>i</sub> and SOC<sub>j</sub><sup>R</sup> are both system variables and are 
   continuous between 0 and 100, that represent the state of 
   charge of a vehicle which determines its travelling range at a particular node.

**Indices**

All indices (i,j,l,m,h,k,b)  pertain to nodes in a network and refer to distinct nodes when used within a particular constraint. indices i and j will be the focus of my problem.

**Logic**

IF (X<sub>ij</sub> = 1 AND (SDV<sub>lmj</sub> = MDV<sub>hkbj</sub> = 0) THEN (SOC<sup>L</sup><sub>i</sub> = SOC<sub>j</sub><sup>R</sup>).

When this logic does not hold true, I want the values for SOC<sup>L</sup><sub>i</sub> and SOC<sub>j</sub><sup>R</sup> to be non-binding.

Additional notes on other current constraints that might shed more light (no need for help on these).

1. SDV<sub>lmj</sub> + MDV<sub>hkbj</sub> <= 1 for all j
2. SDV<sub>lmj</sub> or MDV<sub>hkbj</sub> can only be = 1  if X<sub>ij</sub> = 1 for all nodes j. But X<sub>ij</sub> can be = 1 even if both SDV<sub>lmj</sub> and MDV<sub>hkbj</sub> are = 0. (*I have this down already. Just providing more context for the logic im trying to achieve*)

**What I have so far...**

(1) SOC<sup>L</sup><sub>i</sub> <= SOC<sub>j</sub><sup>R</sup> + BigM(1-X<sub>ij</sub>)

(2) SOC<sup>L</sup><sub>i</sub> => SOC<sub>j</sub><sup>R</sup> - BigM(1-X<sub>ij</sub>)

(3) SDV<sub>lmj</sub>+MDV<sub>hkbj</sub><=1

(4) SDV<sub>lmj</sub>+MDV<sub>hkbj</sub><= X<sub>ij</sub>

The problem with this current formulation however, is that when (SDV<sub>lmj</sub> + MDV<sub>hkbj</sub>) = 1, X<sub>ij</sub> must be equal to 1 based on constraint (4), which multiplies the BigM in constraints (1) and (2) by zero, effectively binding the values  SOC<sup>L</sup><sub>i</sub> to equal SOC<sub>j</sub><sup>R</sup> which I am trying to avoid.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @gravityman123, if the question is still relevant you should consider posting it at www.or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi @dhasson, will do. Thanks for the tip.